# CMD lines work fine but not in .bat file, it just instantly closes?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I tested the folowing lines in cmd ("ctrl + r" ---> "cmd")
and it works fine , but it doensn't work in .bat file , cmd comes up and then instantly closes

Here is my code

```
D:
cd D:\Java\Projects\Jasper\random-jasper-lib\
mvn clean install
cd D:\Java\Projects\Jasper\random-jasper\
mvn clean install
pause
```

How can I get the window to Stay open ?? (preferably even if there are errors)

Comment: Using XP (and tried putting "call " before lines 1 to 5)

Comment: Related reading: http://serverfault.com/questions/283924/keep-command-window-open-after-running-bat-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mvn` is a batch file.

If you call one batchfile from another, you have to use `call` otherwise the calling batch file will be terminated:

Using the `/d` for the `cd` command is also a good idea.

```
cd /d D:\Java\Projects\Jasper\random-jasper-lib\
call mvn clean install
cd /d D:\Java\Projects\Jasper\random-jasper\
call mvn clean install
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not with the `pause` command? -alternatively put `cmd /k` on the very last line of your script.

```
cd /d "D:\Java\Projects\Jasper\random-jasper-lib"
start /b "" "mvn" clean install
cd /d "D:\Java\Projects\Jasper\random-jasper"
start /b "" "mvn" clean install
cmd /k
```

Comment: Thx man, but it stops after executing line 2, if i copy and paste line 3 (after it stopped) then line 3 works

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
PUSHD D:\Java\Projects\Jasper\random-jasper-lib\
mvn clean install
POPD
PUSHD D:\Java\Projects\Jasper\random-jasper\
mvn clean install
POPD
PAUSE
```

save as test.bat and execute it from cmd. that way it won't close the shell and you can see the errormessages

Comment: then I guess there's no random-jasper folder there.

Comment: there is, After the code stops i enter "PUSHD D:\Java\Projects\Jasper\random-jasper" and it then go's to that Dir